# symfony 2.8.8 How to check framework connects to mysql(mariadb)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, mariadb

I am using Symfony 2.8.8. framework and am quite hooked onto it for developing my first web application. The symfony book is very useful. I am on the database and doctrine chapter.

The question I have is: Is there a simple way to know that the database is functional and symfony is able to connect to the database before writing the  doctrine class files that generate the database/entities?

I am using the following environment:

> PHP: 5.5.38 cli,
>   SYMFONY: 2.8.8,
>   DATABASE: mariadb 10.0.17 installed through XAMPP v5.6.23. launched using XAMPP control panel 3.2.2,
>   WEBSERVER: php internal web server with loading of php.ini file.
>   INI:php.ini uncommented extension=php_mysql.dll, extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll.   Updated parameters.yml to point to hosted mariadb.Updated config.yml to use pdo_mysql driver
>   OS: windows 7

Comment: HI Puya,Thanks for your response. I tried this with the use of doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository. I am getting error "undefined method getEntityManager". Can you help me identify the problem.

THough I am using the below command:
 
php -S 127.0.0.1:44 -t <path> -c <path>\Php.ini


C:\php\>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)

Checked on the extensions loaded it shows PDO and mysqlnd is loaded. Am I missing any extensions?

[PHP Modules
mysqlnd
odbc
PDO
checked dll files in the php ext folder. (php_pdo_mysql,php_mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. I'm not sure if its the same for mariadb.

Create a controller and past this inside the controller.

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager() ;

try {
$entityManager->getConnection()->connect();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
// failed to connect
}
```

[EDITED]

I did some research and it seems like getEntityManager(); is deprecated since 2.3

You can use

```
// Get the entity manager
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
// Connection will be written as
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
```

Or

Check this documentation [Doctrine connection](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html)

Comment: symfony doesnt care what db type it is. thats why it abstracts it with doctrine.  Although tbh, symfony will throw an error before it gets this far anyway if theres no db connection

Comment: There you have it :D Thnx DevDonkey

Comment: HI Puya,Thanks for your response. I tried this with the use of doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository. I am getting error "undefined method getEntityManager". Did some analysis here is what I could collect.

Comment: try it like this $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();